# what does the pointer assignment " *foo++ = *bar++; " do in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm sure this has been asked many times before but this kind of thing is pretty difficult to search for.
Say foo and bar are both pointers to separate arrays, what does this line do?

```
*foo++ = *bar++;
```

At what point does each pointer get incremented, and is it an assignment of pointers or values?
Thank you

Comment: To better understand such code, I like to put in the implied parentheses. Look up the precedence of * and ++, and wrap the higher-binding operation in (). ++ is higher precedence than *, so it would be `*(foo++) = *(bar++);`. Now the value pointed to by bar is copied to the place pointed to by foo, and both pointers incremented. Note that the original foo and bar (before increment) are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*foo++ = *bar++;
```

copies what `bar` points at over what `foo` points at.  Then it increments both pointers to the next element.

Comment: How do you know the increments occur *after* the copy?

Comment: @KeithThompson:   I know this because this very statement was presented as an idiom in the original K&R.

Comment: Yes it was, but K&R doesn't say that the increment occurs *after* the copy (I'm looking at K&R1 pages 100-101). And in modern C, since there's no sequence point within the expression, the modifications of `*foo`, `foo`, and `bar` can occur in any of 6 possible orders. (And if the order matters, the behavior is undefined.)

Comment: @KeithThompson:  The context of the example (as I recall) is inside a for loop which exists to copy a block to another block.  The only way it could do what it does is by the pointers being incremented *afterwards*.  If it preincremented, there would have to be additional setup code adjusting the pointers to perform the intended operation.

Comment: I'm talking about the semantics guaranteed by the C standard. The expression has 3 distinct side effects, and the C standard says nothing about the order in which they occur. Realistically, operations can be pipelined. If you write code whose behavior depends on the order, then an optimizing compiler can do anything it likes by *assuming* that your code's behavior is defined. In this particular case, it doesn't matter, but more generally you can very easily shoot yourself in the foot by writing code that depends on ordering that's not guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

the postfix ++ operator will increment the pointer, but the result of the expression `foo++` is the address stored in the pointer *before* the increment.  What is dereferenced is the value of `foo` and `bar` before being incremented.  The assignment then happens on those types.  It's roughly equivalent to

```
*foo = *bar;
++foo;
++bar;
```

If you're unfamiliar, incrementing a pointer causes it to point to the next element in a sequence.  The following two loops accomplish the same task

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    p[i] = 0;
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; ++i, ++p) { // NOTE the extra ++p
    *p = 0;
}
```

generally you increment a pointer as long as the value being pointed to is not equal to some "end" value.  With `char*` this is usually the `'\0'` character.  the example you posted is seen often in a `while` loop using two `char*` types.  `while(*foo++ = *bar++)`.  This loop will continue until the value assigned to `*foo` is of `0` value, which the `\0` character is.

Comment: Nitpicks: *...expression evaluates to what the pointer was **pointing to** before the increment operation. What is **referenced** is the value...* - I think that OP has some confusion on whether the pointers or values are fiddled by the code. Better be clear about where the pointers are used and where the values are.

Comment: @anatolyg I see how that could be confusing.  hard to tell precisely how weak OP's understanding of pointers is though, I'm not sure how much more explanation is warranted but I have changed it

Answer (score 2):

Since post-increment has higher precedence than (binds more tightly than) the unary `*` operator, this:

```
*foo++ = *bar++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(foo++) = *(bar++);
```

The expression `foo++` yields the unmodified value of `foo`; likewise, `bar++` yields the unmodified value of `bar`. (That's not all it does; we'll get to the rest in a moment.) So the assignment copies the value of the object that `bar` points to into the object that `foo` points to. So far, it's equivalent to:

```
*foo = *bar;
```

which I presume doesn't need further explanation.

The value of the expression `foo++` is  simply the value of `foo`, but as a side effect it also causes the value of `foo` to be incremented. `foo = foo + 1` has the same side effect (though it yields a different value). So evaluating

```
*foo++ = *bar++;
```

will *at some point* cause both `foo` and `bar` to be incremented. For this to make sense, both `foo` and `bar` need to point to elements of an array, and each will be advanced to point to the next element of the array.

The time at which these side effects occur is not specified. The values of `foo` and `bar` could be updated in either order, before or after `*foo` is updated. As long as `foo` and `bar` are distinct pointers, this doesn't matter, since the three side effects can't interfere with each other.

Finally, the assignment is itself an expression, and the value it yields is the value that was stored in `*foo`. In this case, that value is discarded.

Breaking it down, and assuming `foo` and `bar` are of type `some_type*`, `*foo++ = *bar++;` could be written as:

```
some_type *foo_tmp = foo;
some_type *bar_tmp = bar;
*foo_tmp = *bar_tmp;
foo = foo + 1;
bar = bar + 1;
```

with the three assignments being executed in some unspecified order (any of the 6 possible orders is allowed). If the order matters, the behavior is undefined. This expansion ignores the value yielded by the assignment.

This kind of expression can be used to implement the `strcpy()` function:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    while (*dest++ = *src++)
        ;
}
```

All the copying is done by the assignment expression that's used as the condition in the `while` loop, and the test for completion of the loop is based on the value that the assignment yields, i.e., the `char` value that was copied. The loop terminates when the value copied is a null character, `'\0'`, which is treated as a false condition. It's a bit too terse for some people's tastes, mine included, but it's a common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Take a simple example:

```
char s1[] = "I am bar";
char s2[10];

char* bar = s1;  // bar points to the first element of s1
char* foo = s2;  // foo points to the first element of s2

*foo++ = *bar++; // Copies 'I' to s2[0]
                 // Now bar points to the second element of s1
                 // foo points to the second element of s2

*foo++ = *bar++; // Copies ' ' to s2[1]
                 // Now bar points to the third element of s1
                 // foo points to the third element of s2
```

Answer (score 0):

post-increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`. Therefore, the following statements are equivalent

```
*foo++ = *bar++;
// equivalent to
*(foo++) = *(bar++);
```

> At what point does each pointer get incremented, and is it an
>   assignment of pointers or values?

`foo++` evaluates to `foo`. Its side-effect is to increment the pointer `foo` to make it point to the next element.

Similarly `bar++` evaluates to `bar` and its side-effect is to make `bar` point to the next element. **Therefore, this statement assigns the object pointed to by `bar` to the object pointed to by `foo`**. **The side-effects take place before the next sequence point**. In this case, it is the end of the statement marked by the semi-colon. Therefore, the pointers `foo` and `bar` are incremented after the assignment statement is executed.

Comment: No, the side effect takes place *before* the next sequence point. And the value of `foo` after the side effect is `foo + 1`, not `foo + sizeof(*foo)`; the `+` operator performs the same scaling as `++`. If you want to demonstrate the scaling, you could write `(target_type*)((char*)foo + sizeof(*foo))`, where `target_type` is the type of `*foo`.

Comment: @KeithThompson True. That was a mistake. Corrected. Thanks :)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for the suggestion. Please have a look. It should be fine now.

Comment: There are three side effects: modifications to `foo`, `bar`, and `*foo`. These side effects can occur in *any* of the 6 possible orders. It's not the case that the increments must occur after the assignment. And I understand the intent of the expression `foo + sizeof(*foo)` but it's potentially misleading, since it's also a valid C expression that means something else.

Comment: @KeithThompson Assignment is also a side-effect here? I understand that it is in expressions like `int b = (a = 4);` but if I have `int a = 4;` isn't its meaning is to assign `4` to `a`? It's the *effect* of the statement as apposed to being a `side-effect`. Please shed some light.

Comment: @ajay they have the same order of precedence, with right to left associativity. See [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @ajay: An assignment expression `a = b` yields a *result* (the value that was assigned) and has a *side effect* (it modifies `a`). The side effect just happens to be the main purpose, but the distinction is still the same.

Comment: @RSahu what is *they* here? `++` and `*`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Much thanks for clarification and enlightenment :)

Comment: @ajay yes, I meant `++` and `*` by *they*.

Comment: @RSahu `++` has higher precedence than `*`. It's clearly mentioned in the link you posted.

Comment: @ajay their order of precedence is same -- 3 (that's the value in the first column) even though `++` shows up higher than `*` in that row of the table. The best test is to try the code and see it behaves the way you are expecting it to. I'll try it to verify my understanding.